# Replacement for Apache AbortableHttpRequest in httpclient5?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

We have code for a proxy servlet that includes this:

```
//abort request, according to best practice with HttpClient
if (proxyRequest instanceof AbortableHttpRequest) {
    final AbortableHttpRequest abortableHttpRequest = (AbortableHttpRequest)proxyRequest;
        abortableHttpRequest.abort();
}
```

This bit of code was copied from some example many years ago. (You can find this code snippet in multiple tutorials with the same comment.)

In httpclient 4, `AbortableHttpRequest` was deprecated in favor of `HttpExecutionAware`. However, neither interface exists in httpclient 5.

Can anyone tell us if there is a recommended replacement for these interfaces in httpclient5?

Note that the [httpclient5 migration document](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/index.html) did not have any information about the removal of these interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Use `CancellableDependency` or `Cancellable` interfaces instead.

Comment: Is there a request type that implements these?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is